# Overriding Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View is a bug in magento?

Tags: magento

I'm trying to override `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` in magento. I have tried to override the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State` and it is working properly, but the `layer_view` rewrite does not. Is this a bug?

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <layer_view>Mymodule_Catalog_Block_Layer_View</layer_view>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>


<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <layer_state>Mymodule_Catalog_Block_Layer_State</layer_state>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

please help me out.I'm trying it from hours

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "it is working properly but not this module". Which class is "it"?

Comment: Mymodule_Catalog_Block_Layer_State is working properly which is in same directory but not Mymodule_Catalog_Block_Layer_View..

Answer (score 5):

Best way to diagnose it is to verify the classname rewrite yourself. In `./demo.php`:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app();

$layer = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('catalog/layer_view');

var_dump($layer);
```

You should see your custom module block classname being returned rather than the core block classname. If that is the case then you need to step through and determine what the issue is. This block is highly coupled to several other block instances and can be a pain to work with.

Also, note that the `Mage_CatalogSearch` module has a `layer_view` block which extends from the `Mage_Catalog` `layer_view` block, *which will not use your override.*

Comment: Thank you very much.. my problem got solved.I should have overrided Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_layer.

Comment: Good, hope that my answer helped point you in the right direction. The two intersecting blocks for these modules is unfortunate.

Comment: I can find only Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Layer which extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View in one of my magento stores (1.6.1.0. C.E.). So it means if anyone wants to make some changes with catalogsearch layered navigation filters then override this block - Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Layer. Thanks for pointing that out Mr.Ben

Answer (score 1):

Best Way to find which class is used by your .phtml is put `echo get_class($this)` in it.

Since I am using Enterprise edition, my layered navigation is not use the Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View. Instead it uses the Enterprise_Search_Block_Catalog_Block_Layer_View class.

When I override that class every thing was sorted out for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have used below mentioned code:

in config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <PKR_Advmixfilter>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </PKR_Advmixfilter>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <layer_view>PKR_Advmixfilter_Block_Layer_View</layer_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

and created a block view file.

```
class PKR_Advmixfilter_Block_Layer_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View {

    public function getFilters()
    {
        $filters = array();
        if ($categoryFilter = $this->_getCategoryFilter()) {
            $filters[] = $categoryFilter;
        }

        $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
        foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
            $filters[] = $this->getChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter');
        }

        return $filters;
    }
}
```

It is working at my end. So there is no bug. :)